# Is a zero vector a "singularity" of a vector field?

Tags: reference-request, terminology, vector-fields

I am studying simple concrete forms of "vector fields" $V: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ with some fixed $r\in\mathbb{N}$. In some texts I am reading the term "singularity" is used for the zero vector $v_z=(0,\dots,0)^T$. I find this very disturbing, because I use singularity for points in the domain where no function values are defined, which is clearly not the case here.

Can anyone tell about the usage of the terminology "singularity" especially in context with vector fields that may justify this?

Comment: You can think that a vector field is an object that which assigns a vector (i.e. an objetc with direction and module) to each point in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Think for example in a velocity field or a electric field. Then the point $(0, \ldots, 0)^T$ dosen´t have a direction, so if in a point the vector field assing the zero vector you don't know which is the direction, or another way to say this, the direction is no defined. I believe that this is the reaseon to use the word "singularity" like a similarity to what you say.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. I wonder if there is a way to formalize this argument?